# Mysql query to print values in a new row delimited by commas

Tags: mysql, replace

In my mysql table i have both comma seperated and without comma seperated values in a column. I need to get the values for all the rows in a column and if there is comma seperated value in a particular row then the values should return as a new row. For eg, i have,

```
a
d,e
f
s,w,h
```

The number of commas is not fixed. I have tried the following query `SELECT replace(description,',',CHAR(13)) FROM errorcodes` and it works fine. Only thing i need now is when it splits in commas i need the values to come in a new row. Right now it splitting but giving the value in a new line but not new row. Please help how to do.

**Note :**
The expected output is -

```
a
d
e
f
s
w
h
```

All in a new row.

Comment: may i know u r expected output example?

Comment: Hi there. I'm commenting here because you deleted your heavily-downvoted question that I was in the middle of commenting on. You have 600+ rep, so you'll be aware that we discourage 'dump and run' questions on Stack Overflow. If you need a regex, please supply the code you've tried in a new question, and what specifically you are having trouble with. Thanks `:)`

Comment: @halfer Hi halfer, i have put up the question again with little description along with the regex expression i have tried. I am native to regex, if you can please help. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826109/cannot-construct-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the custom function and it solved my purpose. Anyone need this can the refer the below code and change the table names and column names accordingly :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS explode_table $$
CREATE PROCEDURE explode_table(bound VARCHAR(255))

  BEGIN

    DECLARE value VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE splitted_value VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT errorcodes.description
                                         FROM errorcodes
                                         WHERE errorcodes.description != '';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2(
    `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=Memory;

    OPEN cur1;
      read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO value;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(value)
                                 - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, bound, ''))
                                 +1);
        SET i=1;
        WHILE i <= occurance DO
          SET splitted_value =
          (SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, bound, i),
          LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, bound, i - 1)) + 1), ',', ''));

          INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (splitted_value);
          SET i = i + 1;

        END WHILE;
      END LOOP;

      SELECT * FROM table2;
    CLOSE cur1;
  END; $$
```

Now just simply calling `CALL explode_table(",")` gives the output in the desired format.