# Cannot construct regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex expression for some validation. I want to check if a string is a combination of atleast one alphabet and one integer. For this i have tried this `^(?=.*[\w][\d]).+` I don't understand regex much. This expression checks for both aplhabet and number in a string but it wants the string to have an alphabet at the start. Instead i just want to check if both alphabet and number are present in a string irrespective of the number and order of occurence. Also the alphabet can be both capital or small so i guess the word checking will be case insensitive. The string might contain special characters along with word and digit in any combination and order but any space should be discarded. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use two lookaheads:

```
/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])/i
```

Comment: hi this is working exactly the way i want. Can you just tell me i more thing. How do i check in the above regex if the string contains any whitespace. I also want to discard if a string contains any space in between letters in a string or at the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Blender's answer is correct, however I would recommend going for a regex that is easier to understand.

What you're looking for is really one of two scenarios: a string of characters that includes a letter first then a number sometime afterwards or the reverse.

The first scenario would then be: `/.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*/`.

The second scenario would be: `/.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*/`.

You can then combine these into one statement:

```
/(.*[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*)|(.*[0-9].*[a-zA-Z].*)/
```

This can be simplified further but I hope this gives you some idea of how to approach regex problems like this.